# OData TimeOfDay to Entity-Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, odata

We would like to use Microsoft.OData.Edm.Library.TimeOfDay as a property on a class so we can use OData queries on the time of day. We use Entity-Framework 6 to persist the data.

There doesn't seem to be a way to make a TimeOfDay property map to a column in the database - using the fluent API to set

```
`modelBuilder.Types<C>().Configure(ctc => ctc.Property(c => c.TimeOfDay.Ticks)
.HasColumnName("TimeOfDay"));`
```

doesn't work because you get a

> The property cannot be configured. Only scalar properties can be
>   configured using the Property method.

exception (I believe because `TimeOfDay.Ticks` doesn't have a setter).

The best we have come up with so far (prettiest in JSON - we tend to care only about simple fractions of an hour) is to use

```
`double HourOfDay { get; set; }`
```

and convert to TimeOfDay as needed.